# Using reactiveFileReader in Shiny app to update a dataframe upon change to underlying CSV

Tags: r, csv, shiny, reactive-programming

I'm working on a complex (for me) Shiny app ~2500 lines of code. The basic structure is as follows, though I can't necessarily share a reproducible example since most of the information is confidential.

Right now, I am using `df1 <- read.csv()` etc to read in several CSV files as dataframes. I want to use `reactiveFileReader()` to make it such that the dataframes automatically update when the source CSV file is modified. I think my problem may be related to the fact that I am not doing this in a reactive context, but there is a reason for this. I am using the dataframes `df1` etc to perform many calculations and to create new variables throughout the app (UI and server sections).

It also might be important to note that I am doing these file imports in the UI part of the Shiny app, since I need to rely on the factor levels of these dataframes to populate drop down `selectInput` in my UI. This might not be necessary.

Here is what I have tried (although I am pretty lost):

```
reader <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, filePath = 
"Data_Record.csv", readFunc = read.csv)

  data_record <- reactive({
    data_df <- reader()
    return(data_df)
  })
```

What I was expecting was for `data_record` to be a dataframe containing the information from the CSV, but it ends up being a "reactive expression". When I try to perform operations on `data_record`, like subsetting, I receive errors since that variable is not a dataframe.

Is there any way for me to update these dataframes upon modification to the underlying CSV outside of a reactive context? Even a scheduled update like every 10 seconds or so would work as well. **My ultimate goal are dataframes that update when a CSV is modified, but scheduled updates are fine as well.**

Thanks in advance for all the help and I apologize for not being able to supply a reproducible example! I will try to add more information as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want the data to be reactive, it has to be imported in the server section of the app as a 'reactive'. In shiny, 'reactives' become functions so to do anything with them you have to reference them their name followed by parenthesis inside a reactive function (reactive, observe, render etc).

For example, with your code above, `reader` becomes a reactive data frame. You can perform normal data manipulation on `reader` if you follow the rules of reactives outlined above.

```
# server.R

reader <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, filePath = 
"Data_Record.csv", readFunc = read.csv)

filtered_reader_df <- reactive({
  reader() %>% filter(x > 100)
})
```

Where `filtered_reader_df` becomes a reactive filtered version of the reactive csv file. Again, to use `filtered_reader_df` in subsequent reactive function it must be referenced as `filtered_reader_df()` as it is a reactive function itself.

Finally, you can still use the reactive csv file to populate UI elements with the `updateSelectInput()` function inside an observer in the server. For example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("mySelectInput", "Select")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  reader <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 1000, filePath = 
                                 "Data_Record.csv", readFunc = read.csv)

  observe({
    select_input_choices <- unique(reader()$factor_column)

    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "mySelectInput", choices = select_input_choices)
  })

}
```

The code above will update the choices of the select input every time the `reader()` data frame changes with the `reactiveFileReader` where `unique(reader()$factor_column)` are the reactive unique values of the factor column you want to populate the input with.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul! I understand the premise of you answer for the most part, and will work to try and implement it this afternoon. I think I still have a little uncertainty on how to work with the reactive dataframe. For example, in my app, I want to add about 10 new computed columns to `reader`. How can I do this conveniently all in one `reactive`? Previously, I was doing something like `reader$col1 <- some calculations` etc. but I'm not sure how I can wrap this all into the reactive. Or if I want to create a new dataframe based on the reactive `reader` that will then be used elsewhere

Comment: Hi @doublestufcoreo , I'd encourage you to watch the reactivity section of the shiny instructional video starting at the 47.25 mark https://vimeo.com/131218530 . My first example above shows you how to create a reactive data set from the reactive reader. To make new columns I would use `dplyr::mutate` inside the reactive function like: 
`reader_wNewCols <- reactive({
  reader() %>% 
    mutate(newCol1 = colX + colY)
})`